# Restrict Access to wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

Basically on my website launch I will be offering users a lot of app promo codes to get apps free. However, I want to know if there is a way that I can make it so that once they have clicked a page they are unable to access any of the others and get all the promo codes basically. So once they have one they are prevented from doing any more.
Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible, because you can't denie a random visitor of your website access to a page if they just read an other page.

Maybe it would be possible if you make sure visitors can only read pages if they got an account. That way you can instal a page restric plugin and edit it yourself by adding a variable that checks how many posts are read and activites the page restrict plugin when x posts are read.

Never done something like this myself, and i dont see why you wouldnt provide all your promo codes to everyone, but thats your own choise:p

I might be completely wrong, but this is what i think.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wordpress plugin called [S2Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/s2member/) to help you restrict pages/posts from guest users.